# Is the dot operator (.) a "real" operator?

Tags: c++, operators

Based on my understanding, operators in C++ take operands that can either be primitive data types or objects or literals.

For example, the `+` operator takes two operands (that can either be primitive data types or objects or literals), for example:

```
result1 = an_int_var + a_float_var;

result2 = obj1 + obj2;

result3 = 2 + 5;

result4 = obj1 + an_int_var;

result5 = obj1 + 5;

result6 = an_int_var + 5
```

But I have noticed that the `.` operator takes an operand which is not a primitive data type nor an object nor a literal, for example:

```
var1 = obj1.age;
```

`obj1` is an object, but what is `age` exactly (it is not a primitive data type nor an object nor a literal)?!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the [member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators).  In this context, `age` is an [id-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_expressions).

Nothing says that all operators must take "primitive data types" or objects or literals, either -- and the ones that can may allow them on one side but not the other.  The [assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment) (`=`) can work with a literal on the right hand side, for example, but cannot on the left hand side.  (`foo = 0;` can make sense depending on what `foo` is, but `0 = foo;` cannot ever make sense.)

Even `::` is considered an operator (the "scope resolution" operator) and that's typically used with namespace/type names on the left, and namespace/type/member names on the right.